# Grid cell does not disappear from layout after animation end

Tags: html, css

When my animation ends, my bottom_row element should disappear (as `display: none` is set at `100%`), but it does not happen. Why?

```css
  .bottom_row {
    opacity: 1;
    animation: hide 5s linear 0s 1 normal forwards running;
  }

  @keyframes hide {
    0% {
      opacity: 1;

    }

    95% {
      opacity: 0.05;
    }

    100% {
      opacity: 0;
      display: none;
      color: red;
      font-size: 48px;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="header_nav_container">
      <div class="top_row">
        TOP ROW CONTENT
      </div>
      <div class="bottom_row">
        BOTTOM ROW CONTENT
      </div>
      <div class="third_row">
        THIRD ROW CONTENT
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
</html>
```

If I simply set **display: none;** right away, the cell is not present in the layout (which is what I want at the end of my anim):

```css
  .bottom_row {
    opacity: 1;
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="header_nav_container">
      <div class="top_row">
        TOP ROW CONTENT
      </div>
      <div class="bottom_row">
        BOTTOM ROW CONTENT
      </div>
      <div class="third_row">
        THIRD ROW CONTENT
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I make an element disappear from the layout / grid without js? Is it possible and why it does not work with animations?

Comment: You cannot animate display property. You will need to use Javascript if you want to remove it from the DOM after animation ends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `height: 0;overflow:hidden;` instead and you will get the same visual result:

```css
.bottom_row {
  opacity: 1;
  animation: hide 5s linear  forwards ;
}

@keyframes hide {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  95% {
    opacity: 0.05;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    color: red;
    font-size: 48px;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="header_nav_container">
    <div class="top_row">
      TOP ROW CONTENT
    </div>
    <div class="bottom_row">
      BOTTOM ROW CONTENT
    </div>
    <div class="third_row">
      THIRD ROW CONTENT
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Nice trick and this seems to be the only non-javascript solution.